# HTTP Basic Auth in Rails while disabling other authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, basic-authentication

I have an application that has user authentication using Devise and Authy, and I want to add API access with a separate set of users in a model (`ApiUser`), for now just using Basic Authentication.  I have the following code in my controller:

```
class Api::SomethingsController < ApplicationController
   load_and_authorize_resource param_method: :something_params          
   skip_authorize_resource            
   skip_authorization_check           
   skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token  
   skip_before_action :authenticate_user!         
   skip_before_action :enable_authy   

   before_filter :api_authenticate    

   private    
   def api_authenticate   
     authenticate_with_http_basic do |userid, password|       
       user = ApiUser.find_by(userid: userid, passwd: password)     
       user
     end      
   end
```

However, no authentication is done - I get results with no authentication at all.

What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 0):

Use `authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic` instead.

```
def api_authenticate   
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic("Somethings Authentication") do |userid, password|       
        user = ApiUser.find_by(userid: userid, passwd: password)     
        user
    end      
end
```